# Regex with optional groups

Tags: regex

I am looking for a single regex to match the following 4 cases (grabbing the id's so I can re-write the urls)

```
http://localhost/gallery/test-name/123456
http://localhost/gallery/test-name/123456/
http://localhost/gallery/test-name/123456/video-name/159
http://localhost/gallery/test-name/123456/video-name/159/
```

Current Regex is below, but its not grabbing ids correctly in all cases. Any experts out there know what I'm doing wrong?

```
^(.*)/gallery/(.*)/([0-9]{1,15})(/)?((.*)/([0-9]{1,15})(/)?)?
```

Comment: Why are you not splitting the string at the `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` (your second use of it) is greedy. So it consumes everything until your last ID. That's why the first ID gets lost if you have two of them. Make it ungreedy instead:

```
^(.*)/gallery/(.*?)/([0-9]{1,15})(/)?((.*?)/([0-9]{1,15})(/)?)?
```

I also added a `?` to the last `.*` in case you want to add more parameters to this. However, simply splitting the string `/` might be much simpler anyway.

Answer (score 1):

By just changing the second `.*` in your regex to `.*?`, you should get the capture groups you expect for your example string:

```
^(.*)/gallery/(.*?)/([0-9]{1,15})(/)?((.*)/([0-9]{1,15})(/)?)?
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/CdBgdA1PlY

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you were wanting, but have you considered something along the lines of:

```csharp
string l_url = "http://localhost/gallery/test-name/123456/video-name/159";
string l_id = l_url.Split( '/' )[5];
```

As you did not specify a language, the above is in C#, but could be easily converted to any other language.